# Python retrieve string input from int(input()) exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make the following code work:

```
try:
    x = int(input())
except ValueError as var:
    #print the input of the user
```

If I try to `print(var)` it would print the error line and not the original input of the user.
For example, if the user would insert `bla` instead of an integer I would like to print `bla`

P.S I must not change the line `x = int(input())`, else I would've solved it easily

Comment: If you know how to fix your code by changing the line `x = int(input())`, just do that.

Comment: What did you try already?  One of the expectations of stackoverflow is that you post what you tried, rather than just ask for an answer.

Comment: `If I try to print(var) it would print the error line` what did you expect then? `var` represents the error

Comment: That's a long exercise. One of the requirements was to get the user input this way exactly. Been looking for a hour how to do this and still no help.

Comment: If you cannot change the `x = int(input())` line, then the value originally returned by `input()` will be lost. There is not much you or us can do about it.

Comment: Well, as I said, nothing from what I've tried worked, plus couldn't find any similar question in google, that's why.

Comment: "P.S I must not change the line `x = int(input())`, else I would've solved it easily." What do you have against solving it easily? Good programs always use easy solutions when they can. You might be able to parse it out of the exception message, but that's about it, and that's a ridiculous and unreliable way of doing this. Storing the value of `input()` is *clearly* the right way to solve this. This exercise is teaching you to do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the `x = int(input())` line, but since you ask, here is an ugly hack wich exploits the format of a `ValueError` message:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foobar'
```

by splitting it at first `:` and removing surrounding `'`:

```
try:
    x = int(input())
except ValueError as e:
    original_input = str(e).split(":")[1].strip()[1:-1]
    print(original_input)
```

by the way, **if you are still using Python 2.x, you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`**. In fact old `input` will automatically attempt a conversion to `int` if possible:

```
try:
    x = int(raw_input())
except ValueError as e:
    original_input = str(e).split(":")[1].strip()[1:-1]
    print original_input
```

Comment: @Jjang yes, it will make `int` raise `ValueError` (since it's not a number) and it will be printed.

Comment: I would prefer strip("'") [double quote, single quote, double quote]

Though for readability sake yours might be better.

Comment: How about:     
original_input = str(e).split(':')[1].strip()     
print eval(original_input)     
This will give the really original user input

Comment: @TokSoegiharto every time you use `eval` a kitten dies. Don't use `eval` or a (not necessarily malicious) code injection will happen.

Answer (score 1):

What appears when you print var?
Until you provide that information, here is a possible hackish solution:

```
try:
    x = int(input())
except NameError as var:
    e = str(var)
    print e[6:-16]
```

This is assuming var is equal to

```
NameError: name 'user_input' is not defined
```

where user_input is the user's input.

EDIT: This post assumed the code was running in Python 2.x whereas it seems to be running with Python 3. Leaving this up in case people are wondering for Python 2

Comment: I got `NameError`, too, but I was wondering if that was a quirk of trying to read input from the interactive prompt. Did you try it from a script? Also, using the slicing syntax won't work in general since you don't know the length of the input. You'd need a pattern match, probably a regex.

Comment: I tried it with a script (run from the command line and not IDLE), on ideone.com and through the python interpreter. Always got a NameError.

Comment: You should get ValueError. You did not define user_input and python thought it was a variable

Comment: No, I got an error because in Python 2 it should be raw_input. I will edit my post, give me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

This is hack that reads the input from the passed error message. It handles quotes in the input string and backslashes correctly.

```
#We get input from the user
try:
    x = int(input())
except ValueError as var:
    #we need to find the text between the quotes in the error message
    #but we don't know what kind of quote it will be. We will look for
    #the first quote which will be the kind of quotes.

    #get the location or existence of each kind of quote
    first_dquote = str(var).find('"')
    first_squote = str(var).find("'")

    used_quote = 0
    #if double quotes don't exist then it must be a single quote
    if -1 == first_dquote:
        used_quote = first_squote
    #if single quotes don't exist then it must be a dubble quote
    elif -1 == first_squote:
        used_quote = first_dquote
    #if they both exist then the first one is the outside quote
    else: used_quote = min(first_squote,first_dquote)

    #the output is what is between the quotes. We leave of the end
    #because there is the end quote.
    output = str(var)[used_quote+1:-1]

    #but the error message is escaped so we need to unescape it
    output = bytes(output,"utf_8").decode("unicode_escape")

    #print the output
    print(output)
```